# app crashing when assigning self to __weak in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are in the same ViewController called "MyViewController"

even though it is crashing it's hard to reproduce but we got this crash from the crashlytics...

```
- (void)dismiss {


MyViewController* __weak weakSelf = self;---->//Crashing here

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    MyViewController* __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        CGRect backFrame = strongSelf.shroud.frame;
        strongSelf.shroud.backgroundImageView.frame = backFrame;
        strongSelf.shroud.shadedOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];

        CGRect semiViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, strongSelf.view.frame.size.height, strongSelf.shroud.contentView.frame.size.width, strongSelf.shroud.contentView.frame.size.height);
        strongSelf.shroud.contentView.frame = semiViewFrame;
    }

} 
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    MyViewController* __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf.shroud removeFromSuperview];
        strongSelf.shroud = nil;
        strongSelf.semiViewController = nil;
    }
}];}
```

We are getting the following crash log from the crashlytics:

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39d148f8 _objc_trap() + 18446744073709552000
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39d1495d _objc_inform
    2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39d233cb weak_register_no_lock + 182
    3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39d236ff objc_storeWeak + 110
    4  applicationName                       0x000e8071 -[MyViewController                 dismiss] (MyViewController:144)
    5  UIKit                          0x31f357f9 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 196
    6  UIKit                          0x31de0a93 -[UIGestureRecognizer         _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1138
    7  UIKit                          0x321880bf ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 46
    8  UIKit                          0x31da794f _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 218
    9  UIKit                          0x31da60b3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 298
    10 UIKit                          0x31ddf305 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 772
    11 UIKit                          0x31ddec2b -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 666
    12 UIKit                          0x31db3e55 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
    13 UIKit                          0x31db2521 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7120
    14 CoreFoundation                 0x2f548faf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    15 CoreFoundation                 0x2f548477 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
    16 CoreFoundation                 0x2f546c67 __CFRunLoopRun + 630
    17 CoreFoundation                 0x2f4b1729 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    18 CoreFoundation                 0x2f4b150b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    19 GraphicsServices               0x344106d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
    20 UIKit                          0x31e12871 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Please help me on this issue....

Thanks in advance

Comment: make the weak things to retain

Comment: @nanda change name to `weakSelf` or take strong .

Comment: @llesh Could you please describe a little bit... Where to change the name ?

Comment: @Nanda like `_strong weakSelf`.

Comment: Can you give us the direct Cradhlytics sharing link?

Comment: @Nanda why do you need strong reference there? Why can't you use __weak reference? And why do you check for nil in completion block?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to do the strong/weak dance here, since there is no retain cycle. The block has a strong reference to the view, but the view does not have a strong reference to the block. When the animation finishes, the block releases the view.

Answer (score -1):

Nanda please change your code like this

```
MyViewController* __strong weakSelf = self;
```

Via making this weak you are trying to access weakSelf which is not in memory by which you are getting crash.

Comment: if i use strong then we may get the retain cycle, so to avoid this I used weak reference.

Comment: then in case you have to make an copy of weakSelf I am not sure its only a suggation